# Calcular cantidad de dias en una consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql

Esta es mi primera consulta y espero no ser tan pesado....

Tengo una tabla asi :

```
persona | fecha_desde | fecha_hasta   

juan    | 2019-12-26  | 2020-01-05  
pedro   | 2020-01-02  | 2020-01-20  
pedro   | 2020-01-20  | 2020-01-31  
luis    | 2019-12-20  | 2020-01-03
```

Tengo que obtener una consulta asi :

```
persona | mes         | diferencia_noches  
juan    | 2019-12     | 6  
juan    | 2020-01     | 4  
pedro   | 2020-01     | 30  
luis    | 2019-12     | 12  
luis    | 2020-01     | 3
```

La cual debe arrojarme por persona y por mes la diferencia de dias correspondiente.

Sinceramente no logro hacerla correctamente en una sola instruccion en MySQL.
Puede alguien apiadarse de mi :)
Muchas gracias!!
Rodrigo.

Comment: Agrega por favor tu consulta y de ahí te ayudamos

Comment: Además que no se entiende lo que quieres obtener

Comment: Hola,
Muchas gracias Aprendiz!!  
Lo que tengo que obtener  básicamente  es la suma de días por mes, pero por cada persona, sumando la diferencia de cada registro desde-hasta.  

Intenté con ésta consulta pero no funciona :  

SELECT   
persona,   
concat(month(fecha_hasta), "/",year(fecha_hasta)) as elMes,  
sum(datediff(fecha_hasta, fecha_desde)) as diferencia_noches  

FROM tabla  
Group by persona, year(fecha_desde) , month(fecha_desde)  

Muchas gracias.